# Squaring Polynomial over $\Bbb F_2[X]$ Is Equivalent to Squaring Argument

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Thanks to some assistance below, I can now

> show that if $g(X) \in \Bbb F_2[X]$ then $g(X)^2 = g(X^2)$.

Is there some more direct way to prove this special case (not that the original proof is long):

> Show that if $\beta$ is a zero of $P(X) \in \Bbb F_2[X]$ then so it $\beta^2$.

Further, suppose that $\beta$ is a $N$th root of unity. If $N$ is not of the form $N = 2^d - 1$, then surely we can generate all powers $\beta^j$ with some power $n$, ie $\beta^n = \beta^{j + kN}$ for some integer $k$. (This is not the case for $N = 2^d - 1$ since we repeat: $\beta^{2^d} = \beta^{N+1} = \beta$.) Is this correct?

---

As always, any advice, muchos appreciato!

Comment: See [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem).

Comment: Ok... but I can't see any way that I can apply this. I'm looking at $\beta^r + \beta^s$, not $(\beta + \gamma)^t$... perhaps write $\beta = (\beta + 1) + 1$ (over $\Bbb F_2$)...?

Comment: $(a_0x^n +P(x))^2=a_0^2x^{2n}+(P(x))^2$.

Comment: Ok, so then if $P(\beta) = 0$, then we get... $\beta^n = \beta^{2n}$? Assuming $a_0 \in \Bbb F_2$, so $a_0 = a_0^2$. This would be fine if $\beta$ were in $\Bbb F_2$, but it isn't necessarily...

Comment: Or, wait, are you then suggesting I use induction on $\deg(P)$?

Comment: Ok, so yeah, that's easy using induction on the degree. =P

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do in that last paragraph. Also, I think using $g(X)^2=g(X^2)$ is about as clean as it gets. All proofs of this result revolve around the fact (aka *Freshman's dream*) that in any commutative ring of characteristic two we have
$$(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2$$ and its generalization in Crostul's answer. In particular I don't see how to prove it using the order of the multiplicative group alone (which is what you ostensibly try in that last paragraph), because this is all about how the additive and multiplicative structures mesh.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason I was trying a different method was that, on my example sheet, Q9 included the second part and Q10 the first. The second is a special case of the first, so I thought it might be possible to do a direct proof. I think Q10 might be an old exam question though, possibly - hence the repetition. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$(a_1 + \dots + a_n)^2 = a_1^2 + \dots + a_n^2 + 2 (a_1a_2 + \dots + a_{n-1}a_n)$$
What happens if $2=0$?

Comment: Would you then apply this as André Nicolas has?
$$(a_0x^n +P(x))^2=a_0^2x^{2n}+(P(x))^2.$$
I can then easily show the general case using induction on the degree. I've actually updated my question - I think I updated it while you were typing your answer!